# Remove Empty bags in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop2

I have data like this.

```
(a,b,c,d)
(g,b,v,n)
(n,h,l,o)
(,,,)
(,,,)
(,,,)
(,,,)
```

I want to remove empty bags.
**desired output**

```
(a,b,c,d)
(g,b,v,n)
(n,h,l,o)
```

Comment: Got Answer. Not Null won't works here. Check the size of each column and if size is not zero consider only those records.

Comment: According to the question description I assumed that filtering by null will work. Anyway I updated the answer to include filtering by column size as well so that anyone who encounters the same problem can benefit from it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you could have given the code you have so far.

**Approach One: Filtering By Null Values**

```
-- load comma deliited values into columns
A = load './input.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (one:chararray, two:chararray, three:chararray, four:chararray);
dump A;

-- remove records where columns are null
B = FILTER A BY (one is not null) OR (two is not null) OR (three is not null) OR (four is not null);
dump B;
```

This assumes input.txt as follows.

```
a,b,c,d
g,b,v,n
n,h,l,o
,,,
,,,
,,,
,,,
```

Run command:

```
pig -x local clean.pig
```

Output First Dump:

```
(a,b,c,d)
(g,b,v,n)
(n,h,l,o)
(,,,)
(,,,)
(,,,)
(,,,)
```

Output Second Dump:

```
(a,b,c,d)
(g,b,v,n)
(n,h,l,o)
```

**Approach Two: Filtering By Column Size**

```
-- load comma deliited values into columns
A = load './input.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (one:chararray, two:chararray, three:chararray, four:chararray);
dump A;

-- generate column count
B = FOREACH A GENERATE COUNT(TOBAG(*)),$0..;
dump B;

-- filter by column count
C = FILTER B BY $0 > 0;
dump C;

-- remove column count
D = FOREACH C GENERATE $1..;
dump D;
```

Output of Dump A:

```
(a,b,c,d)
(g,b,v,n)
(n,h,l,o)
(,,,)
(,,,)
(,,,)
(,,,)
```

Output of Dump B:

```
(4,a,b,c,d)
(4,g,b,v,n)
(4,n,h,l,o)
(0,,,,)
(0,,,,)
(0,,,,)
(0,,,,)
```

Output of Dump C:

```
(4,a,b,c,d)
(4,g,b,v,n)
(4,n,h,l,o)
```

Output of Dump D:

```
(a,b,c,d)
(g,b,v,n)
(n,h,l,o)
```

P.S:

If your input file has brackets initially, you might want to handle that separately.